# PreEmptive Dotfuscator not working on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I'm using PreEmptive Obfuscator (Dotfuscator) to obfuscate a Xamarin app. 
My  problem is that the Obfuscator doesn't obfuscate my project dlls. When i open the dll after obfuscation i still see readable information. The obfuscation tool automatically opens when i click build/rebuild button - this proves that i linked/configured it properly.

What could be the problem ? Please see the screenshot below :

[image]

My project file code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe</DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>
    <DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName>DotfuscatorConfig.xml</DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName>
    <DotfuscatorXamarinGenerateNewConfigFile>true</DotfuscatorXamarinGenerateNewConfigFile> 

    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{88F1AA1B-4608-40F7-B14D-C7E28099A26E}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TestDotObfuscator</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TestDotObfuscator</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>True</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled>true</DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled> 
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>PdbOnly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>true</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DB.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="GettingStarted.Xamarin" />
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Main.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\Strings.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="DotfuscatorConfig.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
        Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
        <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        </Target>
        <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        </Target>
    -->
  <Import Project="..\..\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: You mention in your question that "The obfuscation tool automatically opens when i click build/rebuild button" - do you mean that the Dotfuscator user interface (in your screenshot) opens whenever you build your project in Visual Studio? Can you try running the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe` yourself from a command prompt, and see whether that opens the user interface or displays textual information?

Comment: Yes it opens the GUI from Command Prompt.

Comment: Then the `dotfuscatorCLI.exe` is not actually the CLI, but the GUI executable. Was it renamed? Does opening `dotfuscator.exe` at the same path also open the GUI, or does it display textual information?

Comment: Yes, dotfuscator.exe opens the GUI as well. It doesn't encrypt the text.

Answer (score 2):

When Dotfuscator Community Edition is installed (to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE` in your case), `dotfuscator.exe` is the graphical user interface (GUI), and `dotfuscatorCLI.exe` is the command line interface (CLI). (The names and path differ for Professional Edition.)

Based on your edited question and responses to comments, it seems you have somehow replaced `dotfuscatorCLI.exe` with a copy of `dotfuscator.exe`. When the Visual Studio build integration calls `dotfuscatorCLI.exe`, it expects the command line to run, not the GUI.

Please uninstall, then reinstall Dotfuscator Community Edition:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio 2017.
2. From the Start Menu, open the Visual Studio Installer.
3. Under "Visual Studio Community 2017", select *Modify* (it may be under the *More* drop-down).
4. Select the *Individual Components* tab.
5. Scroll down to the *Code tools* section and uncheck the box for *PreEmptive Protection - Dotfuscator*.
6. Click *Modify*.
7. When the uninstall is complete, open *Modify* again.
8. Select the *Individual Components* tab.
9. Scroll down to the *Code tools* section and check the box for *PreEmptive Protection - Dotfuscator*.
10. Click *Modify*.
11. When the installation is complete, open a command prompt.
12. Run: `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE"`
13. Run: `dotfuscator.exe`.
14. Verify that the graphical user interface (GUI) opens.
15. Return to the command prompt and run: `dotfuscatorCLI.exe`.
16. Verify that help text is displayed in the command prompt, and the graphical user interface (GUI) **does not** open.

Then, assuming you have registered Community Edition, you should be able to run your Dotfuscator-integrated Xamarin build in Visual Studio, and the GUI should **not** open when you do so.

Disclaimer: As mentioned in the comments, I also work on the Dotfuscator team, and am answering this question in that capacity.

Comment: i followed your step Joe. It worked. But my main issue still persist - it  does not encrypt the text in the dlls. Do you perhaps know the possible cause ?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on Nathan's answer, string encryption is not part of Community Edition. You will need to [integrate your Xamarin build with Professional Edition](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html) and use the Professional Edition GUI to enable and configure string encryption.

Comment: Thank you Joe. My question has been answered. How can i order a professional version quick ? Can i get it within a day ?

Comment: @chosenOneThabs please [download an evaluation](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads) to get started, and you'll be contacted by a sales person who will be happy to help you place an order for the full version.

Comment: I'm trying the trial version, and i'm getting this error when i compile the project in release mode: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation 4.33.0\dotfuscator.exe" /p:InDir="obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 1.

Comment: @NathanArthur How much is your professional version ? Is  it a once off fee ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you configured the integration to use the GUI executable, rather than the CLI (build) executable. If you are seeing the Dotfuscator GUI appear each time you build your Xamarin app, that's probably the issue.

Depending on whether you are using Dotfuscator Community Edition or Dotfuscator Professional, the executable name might be different. For CE, use `dotfuscatorCLI.exe`. For Pro, use `dotfuscator.exe`.

Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, the company that makes Dotfuscator.

Comment: thats what i'm using. I'm referencing both exe's from :C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE . I followed these instructions : https://dzone.com/articles/safeguard-your-xamarin-apps-from-threats-with-dotf

Comment: @chosenOneThabs Please consult the official instructions in the [Dotfuscator User Guide](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html). In particular, make sure the value of `DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath` is set in your project file to be a path ending with `dotfuscatorCLI.exe`, as you are using Community Edition. (I also work for PreEmptive.)

Comment: @JoeSewell i tried instructions on this link  : https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html , but i'm still encountering the same issue. Do you perhaps have a project that i can download and copy its config settings ? Why does my app open a GUI if i'm referencing the right exe file ?

Comment: @chosenOneThabs [There is a sample for Professional Edition on GitHub](https://github.com/preemptive/protected-bugsweeper), which you can consult, noting that the path and name of the CLI executable differs from Community Edition. You could also try temporarily renaming the GUI executable (`dotfuscator.exe` file) and building to verify you're not referring to that in your build configuration.

Comment: @JoeSewell i configured my app the same way this app is configure : https://github.com/preemptive/protected-bugsweeper . The only difference is that i'm pointing to CLI exe. The issue might be with the Dot Obfustor version that i have installed on my PC. I installed it via Visual Studio 2017, under tools option. How can I confirm that i installed the right version ? Or are there bugs in this version ?

Comment: I tried to request professional version demo on this link : https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/videos-a-resources , sadly i was asked to complete a form first. And I'm still for someone to approve my request.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs Dotfuscator Community Edition lists its version number under *Help -> About...*; the latest version is 5.32. I took the GitHub sample and changed the `DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath` value in the `.csproj` file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe`, but this did not reproduce your issue. Please update your question with more details. If you are going to evaluate Professional Edition instead, you can instead contact technical support for more help.

Comment: @JoeSewell can i send you my code please. I have a sample that i wrote to test DotObfuscator. Still does not work.

Comment: @JoeSewell i have added my project file code. Am i missing something ?

Comment: My code contains sensitive urls in it. So i would like DotObfuscator to encrypt these kind of text -  all hard coded text.

Comment: Thank you for adding your project file to the question, see my comment there. As for string encryption, that is an exclusive feature of Professional Edition, and is therefore not related to this question, which is about Community Edition.